# How to start developing Windows mobile applications

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6, sharpdevelop

I want to write an application for my Windows 6.1 standard smart phone that intercepts incoming SMS messages and auto responds if they match a specific criteria, but despite installing countless SDk's I am unable to do what I need.

The code I want to use relies on the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll assembly, but I can't seem to find that assembly.  Is it possible to use this assembly on a standard mobile device, or do I have to have a Windows Mobile professional device?

So basically I need help getting set up to create Windows Mobile applications.

- I am using SharpDevelop (because I
  can't afford Visual Studio).
- I need the
  Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook
  assembly (Since I have already written code that should work, that uses it).
- A device emulator would also be nice
  so I don't have to test on my phone.

Is what I want to do possible on a Windows 6.1 Standard device (HTC OZone)?

Any help would be appreciated, since I am completely stuck at this point.

Thanks,

I tried to compile my code and I get the following errors, as I suspected I would.

- The type or namespace name
  'WindowsMobile' does not exist in the
  namespace 'Microsoft' (are you
  missing an assembly reference?)

I can't find the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook assembly so of course I'm missing an assembly reference.

Where can I get this assembly, and will this code run on my Windows 6.1 Standard phone if I can find it?

Comment: Make sure you have the Windows Mobile 6 SDK installed. Then you'll be able to find the DLL in C:\Program Files\Windows CE\wce600\Windows Mobile 6.0 Smartphone SDK\DesignTimeReferences\Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll. Use that path when adding a reference to your project.

Comment: I tried adding Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll from Windows Mobile SDK (PocketPC though), it doesn't work with SharpDevelop 3.1.1. The .NETCF version of bundled assemblies in the SDK is 1.0.0.0 while my other .NETCF assemblies are 3.5.0.0. Is this possibly the reason for the error? There's also this warning before the error: "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. (MSB3247)"

Comment: @afriza: What do you mean it doesn't work with SharpDevelop? All I have to do is make a reference to the dll when I compile my code and it should work.  csc.exe /t:library /out:"C:\createFileHEre\myFile.dll" "C:\MySource\Source.cs" /r:"C:\Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll".  What does the IDE have to do with anything?  Thats why I'm so angry that I need to have Visual Studio, what a dumb requirement.

Comment: so you use the command line to compile?

Comment: @afriza: Yes. I usually write my code in a simple text editor, and then use csc.exe to compile.  Well I use response files, and a batch file that runs csc.exe

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it's very difficult for someone new to Windows Mobile development to work without Visual Studio.

In theory you can use SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop, but you wouldn't be able to do any debugging on the emulator or a connected device. Being able to debug by stepping through the code while it's running seems to me an unmissable thing if you're new to Windows Mobile and are not quite sure why something you coded is not working. It requires more effort and time to debug something and in the end you might find it more cost effective to buy a Visual Studio license.

The minimum required is Visual Studio 2005 Standard. You could try to see if you can find somewhere that sells it cheaply (as most developers now use VS2008/2010). If you're a student you could get an academic license or take advantage of Microsoft's [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program. Or if you're a startup you could look at Microsoft's [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) program.

Comment: I'm creating this, and possibly other applications for personal use, so it doesn't make sense to pay for an IDE.

Comment: When I try to install the Windows Mobile SDK, it says Visual Studio 2005 SP1 or later is a prerequisite.  Is there a way to get around this?  or is Microsoft extorting $300 from me?

Comment: Why don't you download Visual C# 2008 Express edition.
It's completely free and has similar features and functionality to visual studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CS

Comment: @Jamie: Express has no device support.

Comment: @Johann: I never knew that, i've never developed for a mobile device. Glad i know now, learn something new everyday.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Express, but I never use it because it's so limited in what it can do.  I just don't see a reason to pay $300 for an IDE.

Comment: @Tester101: You can buy VS2005 Standard already from about $69: http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=visual+studio+2005+standard&cid=13940170157586997226&sa=title#p

Comment: @tomlog: Even so, why should I have to buy something I'm not going to use just to install something I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with sample code that has most of you requirements implemented. The SDK comes with the sample: SMSIM 
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158721.aspx)

It demonstrates how to use C# to write a managed code version of a Short Messaging Service (SMS) interception application.

I hope this helps.
Mike

Comment: As I mentioned, I have the code that should do what I want.  I am having a problem getting setup so I can compile the code, and install it on the device.